# What are the advantages or disadvantages of using blogging platforms?

Tags: domains, wordpress, blog, blogger, blogspot

I want to create a **blog** and I want my own domain. It will be a blog mainly, but I don't exclude to add some sections for contacts and purchasing items from a store later.

- Since some **weblog publishing tools** like Wordpress and Blogger give the possibility to purchase a own domain, I wonder:
  which are the **advantages / disadvantages** of using such platforms instead than creating a website from scratch, with regard to indexing, possibility to earn money with the advertisement, perception of professionalism, possibility to add an e-commerce platform (and other aspects, if any) ?

Comment: There is another option besides hosted tools and creating something from scratch:  running blog software on your own server or home computer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for the suggestion.

If I understand correctly, what you suggest is:
- firstly I should run my blog on Wordpress / Blogger;
- secondly, I should purchase a domain and a host from a Web company like Aruba.
- thirdly, I should import my wordpress-blog into this host.
Is it right? 
(sorry, I have no experience in this domain)

Comment: That was not a suggestion, just another option that you hadn't put in your question.

Comment: This question currently has a vote to close it as "primarily opinion based."  I do not believe that this question is opinion based.   Most advantages and disadvantages of blogging platforms can be easily backed up with statistics, experience, and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advantages** are very few, and they are only for hobby-blogger:

- No technical workload (nothing to setup).
- (Mostly) No troubles with site performance.
- Low entry point (one can start blogging without any background knowledge).
- Security (noone hacks blog platforms).
- Social networking by design (blog platform users are the first and easy-to-reach readers)
- SEO out of the box (free platform templates are mostly enough optimized to provide findability).

---

**Disadvantages** are different, but they appear only if one wants to blog like a pro (make money with):

- No or limited extensions.
- No or limited customization of design, functionality and SEO (no  or limited access to the template source, no access to the core source).
- Limited e-commerce and monetization (one isn't absolutely free in how one monetizes the blog).
- Limited webspace.
- No custom user journey scenarios.
- Visible blog platform footprints (less trust).

Comment: Thank you. What about host services which offer the possibility of creating a PRO blog on CMS platform (e.g. Wordpress on Altersito)? Can I have the advantages of both in such case?

Comment: you should firstly define your goals, and then look, which solution forces you to less compromisses

Answer (score 0):

Blogging is the way to get more backlinks and to enhance huge traffic towards the business. Blogging is the best platform to start SEO. If you participate on the blogs on the regular basis then there is a huge amount of advantages. If you are not perform blogging on a regular basis than it would be the bad impact for you and your business.